# Google Maps Doesn't show data retrieved from database

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

So I'm trying to display data on a Google Map taken from my database(using API 3).I get the correctly centered Google Map but no markers.

Both generateXml.php and ViewMap.php are on same directory.

Please Help me out appriciate it...

Thank you so much in advance.

**generateXml.php**

```
<?php

      require("db_connection.php");


      function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
      { 
          $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
          $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
          $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
          $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
          $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
          return $xmlStr; 
      } 

      // Select all the rows in the markers table
      $query = "SELECT transportType,costPerKm,address,teleNo,webLink,description,lat,lng FROM transportpublic";

      $result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$result) 
      {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
      }

      header("Content-type: text/xml");

      // Start XML file, echo parent node
      echo '<markers>';

      // Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
        echo '<marker ';
        echo 'transportType="' . parseToXML($row['transportType']) . '" ';
        echo 'costPerKm="' . $row['costPerKm'] . '" ';
        echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
        echo 'teleNo="' . $row['teleNo'] . '" ';
        echo 'webLink="' . parseToXML($row['webLink']) . '" ';
        echo 'description="' . parseToXML($row['description']) . '" ';
        echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
        echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
        echo '/>';
      }

      // End XML file
      echo '</markers>';
?>
```

---

```
<markers>
<marker transportType="abc" costPerKm="1.50" address="abc" teleNo="112554476" webLink="http://www.abc.html" description="abc" lat="6.886464" lng="79.871287"/>
<marker transportType="Train" costPerKm="1.50" address="abc" teleNo="112541258" webLink="http://www.abc.html" description="Good" lat="7.284459" lng="80.637459"/>
</markers>
```

---

**ViewMap.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>View Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template/css/style.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map { height: 100% }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="util.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  var infowindow;
  var map;

 function initialize() 
 {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.796396,79.877823);
      var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapC"), myOptions);
    var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
    transitLayer.setMap(map);


    downloadUrl("generateXml.php", function(data) 
    {
      data = xmlParse(data);
      var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
       {
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          bounds.extend(latlng);
          var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("transportType"), latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
     });
  }


  function createMarker(transportType, latlng) 
  {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: transportType});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;

  }



function downloadUrl(url, callback) 
{
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
      if (request.readyState == 4) 
      {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() 
{

}

</script>


</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

    <div id="content123">
        <div style="height:400px">

        <!--dispaly map -->
          <div id="mapC" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

When this line is added to mapView.php

```
<?php include("generateXml.php")?>
```

It doesn't even show the map It gives me the error

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 57 at column 26: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

View Map html { height: 100% } 

body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 } #map { height: 100% } 

var infowindow; var map; 

function initialize() 

{ 

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.886464,79.871287); 

   var myOptions = { zoom: 10, center: myLatlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP} 

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapC"), myOptions); 

   var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer(); transitLayer.setMap(map); 

   downloadUrl("generateXml.php", function(data)

   { var xml = data.responseXML; 

     var markers = data.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); for (var i = 0; i
```

Comment: not sure if it could be related but i had a lot of problems using the maps-api in chrome browser but it works perfectly in other browsers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply but I use Mozilla

Comment: please format your code so it is readable.

Comment: @geocodezip I formatted the code and even added generateXml.php source code

Comment: @geocodezip hey I figured it out I commented following lins from your example and It worked I don't know why :) FINALLY pheeewww

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(latlng);
map.fitBounds(bounds); thanx geocodezip it all thanx to your help your awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "var" from this line:

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapC"), myOptions);
```

so it initializes the global "map" variable rather than creating a new one that is local to the initialize function (the global one is being used in the createMarker function)

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_dataRetrievedFromDB.html) (there are other changes, but the one that fixed it was the map variable)

Comment: thank you so much for the example I removed "var" from that line & even added  
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script> and 

<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js"           type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script> 
But still no luck. :[

Comment: downloadUrl("SO_generateXml_20130402.xml", function(data){.....} sholud I pass the .xml file?

Comment: I used the `downloadxml.js` because I modified it to work for me with local files in IE, you shouldn't need to use it (although it may help with MIME issues).  Don't add the analytics script, that is for tracking my pages.  Perhaps your XML doesn't have the correct MIME type.

Comment: I used alert()s and the alert() inside for loop doesn't display.

Comment: What is "markers.length"?  If you point your browser at the XML does it report errors (as suggested in the [XML example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#outputxml))?

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean when I run generateXml.php ? no it doesn't give any errors but when i run viewmap.php it gives me this error
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost:8080/testserver/ViewMap.php
Line Number 57, Column 26:      
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
-------------------------^

Comment: I can't see your localhost.  Do you have a public URL?  You should not be including it (`generateXml.php`) in your "ViewMap.php".

Comment: I'm sorry no I don't have a public url when I removed that include line I get the map but no markers again because not executing for loop i guess

Answer (score 0):

there's a typo in generateXml lat="7.284459lng="

Comment: @gererd my bad sorry i messed up when editing data here I corrected it thanx 4 pointing that out :)